# Tableview background shows on simulator but is white when played on device

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I currently have a tableview that has a clear background color so an image below it can be seen.  On simulator it works great:

[image]

But when it's played on a device the background turns white:

[image]

The app is still functional but it would be nice to keep the background image.
This is my code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



  var tabBarItems: [UIViewController] = []
  var areMessagesVisible: Bool = false

  var titleForTabBars: [String] = ["Home", "Inbox", "Rewards", "My Card", "Locations", "My Profile", "Account Activity", "Invite Friends",  "About Us", "Settings", "Help"]

  var iconNames: [String] = ["Glass",  "Mail Tab Bar Icon", "Rewards Tab Bar Icon", "TabBar card icon", "Locations Tab Bar Icon", "", "", "","","",""]

  var controllersStoryboardId: [String] = ["homeNavController",  "inboxNavController", "rewardsNavController", "cardNavController", "locationsNavController", "myProfileNavController", "accountActivityNavController", "inviteFriendsNavController", "aboutUsNavController",  "settingsNavController", "helpNavController" ]



  // to manage moreTableView
  var moreTableView: UITableView = UITableView()
  var currentTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate?




  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.customizeMoreTableView()
    //to REMOVE
    areMessagesVisible = true

    if !areMessagesVisible{
      self.titleForTabBars.removeAtIndex(4)
      self.controllersStoryboardId.removeAtIndex(4)
      self.iconNames.removeAtIndex(4)
    }

    for i in 0 ..< controllersStoryboardId.count{
      tabBarItems.append(UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(controllersStoryboardId[i]) as? UINavigationController ?? UINavigationController())
    }


    // change background image
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Blank Settings"))
    backgroundImageView.frame = view.frame
    backgroundImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)

    let backgroundImageView2 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background3"))
    backgroundImageView2.frame = view.frame
    backgroundImageView2.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView2)
    moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView2)


    //change nav bar color
        moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackOpaque
        moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

     }




  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    for i in 0 ..< tabBarItems.count{
      tabBarItems[i].tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: titleForTabBars[i], image: UIImage(named: iconNames[i]), selectedImage: UIImage(named: iconNames[i]))
    }
    self.viewControllers = tabBarItems
  }


  func customizeMoreTableView(){
    moreTableView = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController!.view as? UITableView ?? UITableView()
    currentTableViewDelegate = moreTableView.delegate;
    moreTableView.delegate = self
    moreTableView.dataSource = self;
    moreTableView.registerClass(MoreTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MoreTableViewCell")

  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let moreCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MoreTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MoreTableViewCell ?? MoreTableViewCell()

    moreCell.textLabel?.text = titleForTabBars[indexPath.row + 4]
    moreCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    moreCell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: iconNames[indexPath.row + 4])
    moreCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return moreCell
  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titleForTabBars.count - 4

  }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    currentTableViewDelegate?.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  }

}
```

Comment: Use the View Hierarchy Inspector to see what's causing the white background.

Comment: What does your code look like? How are you setting the the background image?

Comment: I added the code to the original post, it's for a moreViewController off of a TabBarController

Answer (score 1):

there could be two reasons.
the uitableviewcell background is not clear
your image reference is not added in the project target you are running. it happens some times. plz double check.

Answer (score 0):

**In your tableview datasource try to add following code and it worked in my case**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellidentifier")!
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: May be you could add a few words explaining why this is a solution?

Comment: This solved my problem as well, though not sure why there should be a difference between iOS 13 on an iPhone 11 Pro as a device and on the simulator?

Comment: But how can we test any of these solutions if we only have quick access to simulator and not real device? Shouldn't the simulator faithfully replicate what is shown on real device?